# generating a char array of white space in variable length

Tags: c, printf, space

I'm wiring a code in C that is supposed to print to the screen (using printf()) a multiplication table where the bottom right corner (the max product of the table) is passed to the function as MaxMult.

for example for MaxMult = 4 it should print:

```
  1  2  3  4

  2  4  6  8

  3  6  9 12

  4  8 12 16
```

the demands are that the table will be aligned to the right, and here lies my problem:

for each number, the number of white space to its left is different.
and because i need it to follow the demand that the MaxMult has only 1 white space to its left, everything else is in reference to it.

at first I thought maybe I could pass a variable to printf. something like this:

```
printf("% Num_Of_Wite_Space d", currNum)
```

but I can't seem to be able to do this.

so now I need a way to generate a string of white space, different in length according to each number's number of digits, so to pass IT to printf.
(hope i'm clear enough..)

can anybody tell me how to to this?

Answer (score 3):

> something like this:
>
> `printf("% Num_Of_Wite_Space d", currNum)`
>
> but I can't seem to be able to do this.

Of course you can do this. The syntax is:

```
printf("%*d", fieldWidth, currNum);
```

Note that fieldWidth is the total width of (spaces + number).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to just use a fixed field width for each value, e.g.

```
printf("%3d", a[i][j]);
```

This will cause each output value to be padded with leading spaces where necessary to give a field width of 3, e.g.

```
1  2  3  4

2  4  6  8

3  6  9 12

4  8 12 16
```

Obviously if you need to print values with more than two digits you should increase the field width accordingly.

If you need a field width that will be determined at run-time rather than being fixed at compile-time you can use:

```
printf("%*d", field_width, a[i][j]);
```

See [man printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) for further details.

Comment: This won't work for cases when the final (bottom-right) value is longer than 2 digits.

Comment: @unwind: true - it was just an illustrative example for this particular case - I've updated the answer now though to cover different field widths and field widths that are specified at run-time rather than compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

It is not too difficult:

```
int width = 10; //< number of chars in one column
printf("%*d", width, a[i][j]);
```

You can set the column width fixed, or use some computed values from array:

```
int width[COLS];
int a[ROWS][COLS];
int row, col;

... // fill in a and width

for (row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row)
{
    for (col = 0; col < COLS; ++col)
    {
        printf("%*d", width[col], a[row][col]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```